# How to reorder a string in R to follow a consistent pattern

Tags: r, string

I have vector of strings of the type: `2004/083.BHP`, `2007.MAIS.0048` and `2006/0066`. There are lots of these strings of varying characters.

I would like to have consistentcy in the representation of these strings, so that they look something like `083/2004.BHP`, `0048/2007.MAIS` and `0066/2006`.

How do I get all strings in this vector to appear in this way without manually coding it? I understand this is a difficult task, and any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the ordering. Are 2004, 2007 and 2006 dates? Does the other number in a string always start with a 0?

Comment: These are years and a time point. I would like the dates to be ordered as described and any remaining string to be placed at the end.

Comment: Yes, the time point does not always starts with a 0. For instance '2002/107.BHP'

Comment: Is the order currently fixed (always year first) and you want to rearrange it? Thanks simple `substr` or at worst `gsub`. If not, though, what happens when you have a time points after 8pm? When you see `2007/2006.BHP`, what goes where?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions for ordering or sorting your strings in a consistent pattern (such as by alphabetic order or by number of characters).  The last case, sorts by starting with a 4-digit (ie date) and then by name.

```
  strings <- c("2004/083.BHP","2007.MAIS.0048","2006/0066","432.ABC","2008/42002","2094/31.AC")
strings <- sort(strings)
strings
strings <- strings[order(nchar(strings))]
strings
strings <- strings[order(strings,decreasing =T) ]
strings
strings <- strings[order(grepl("^\\d{4}",strings),strings,decreasing =F) ]
strings
```